# sahi - dynamic table

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, sahi

I'm trying to figure out how to find the row number where a particular text value is (it's a dynamically created table, so if something is deleted/added the row num will change.) Then I'd like to get the text from a column in that row (which is always the same [5]), save it to a variable and then do an assert on the saved text. I've seen some code here which allows me to cycle through the rows of a table but I haven't yet seen something which cycles through table rows until it finds something specific, all the examples I've seen always just go to the end of the table in question.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sahi API _near to find the element uniquely.

You can follow the url:
http://sahi.co.in/w/sahi-api-examples

Comment: Awesome, hadn't seen the URL you mentioned and the last example made it crystal clear to me. Thanks very much!  :)